# How to tell firefox to render simple html white on black?

Tags: firefox, html, freebsd, html5, dark-mode

I am no browser expert nor web-dev. I read simple websites and they blind me if use anything more modern than lynx or w3i. However, sometimes these new *modern* websites require the operating systems those modern browsers deliver.

How can I give Firefox a real dark mode?
I enabled Firefox *dark mode* via open `menu -> Customize -> themes -> dark`.
However, simple html pages, are still black letters on white background.

I would like to have Firefox render basic html pages with white or light letters on black or dark background.

I am using Firefox 86.0.1 on a FreeBSD  machine running 12.2-release-p4 on amd64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### I would like to have firefox render basic hmtl pages with white or light letters on black or dark background.

There are several options:

[Dark Background and Light Text – Get this Extension for  Firefox (en-GB)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/dark-background-light-text/):

> Make every web page (or just the pages you want) display light text on dark backgrounds. All color variations are fully customizable.

[Dark Reader – Get this Extension for  Firefox (en-GB)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/darkreader/):

> Dark mode for every website. Take care of your eyes, use dark theme for night and daily browsing.

I'm not going to post a screenshot of your example website as it is full of rude/abusive language.

Comment: [Dark Reader](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/darkreader/) allows you to enable or disable its dark mode on a per site basis.

Comment: @Mokubai Thx. Added that as another option.